# What is the life span of a field in a static class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, garbage-collection

I have a simple web service, in it i have a static class which has a static collection to remember alive tokens.

I just want to make sure that the token collection lives until the next iisreset or the application pool recycles.

And what is the difference between remembering states in Application bag and static class?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft ([says](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312607#4)):

> ASP.NET includes application state primarily for compatibility with classic ASP so that it is easier to migrate existing applications to ASP.NET. It is recommended that you store data in static members of the application class instead of in the Application object. This increases performance because you can access a static variable faster than you can access an item in the Application dictionary.

So, use static variables. And do not forget use `lock`.

Comment: Wow, that's the first time I've heard that.  I would have thought the opposite would be true (prefer Application because it's easier and probably fast enough)

Comment: @greg, @gor: It's news for me too. I hope to see more reactions here.

Comment: What can be faster than accessing static variable ?

Comment: Well, apparently you have to manually lock the Application object anyway, so yeah, you may as well use `static`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your static members won't scale to more than 1 server.