# Do all instances of the same ASPX page share the same static field?

Tags: asp.net, static-members

Let's consider this page's code-behind:

```
public partial class Products : Page
{
    private static SomeClass SharedField;

    public Product()
    {
        // ... Some logic
    }
}
```

Do all `Products` pages instances share the same `SharedField`, I know this is a basic concept of static fields. But in this case, really? all users can have access (and can't have their own instance of) to the same static field on the website-level?

If so, in what aspects this would used by the web developer? or is this non-recommended practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there will be a single instance of that static field for all users, but only within a single worker process.  If you have web farms/web gardens, they will each have their own static instance.  If the worker process restarts, you'll get a new static instance.

You'll have to use locking around that shared field to ensure thread safety.

As for why to use that, I'm not sure, I never do it.  The best example I can give you is the built-in static `HttpContext.Current`, which gives you access to the Request, Response, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`SharedField` will be available in one instance for the entire life-cycle of the web site.

To read a bit more about it, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563171/asp-net-c-static-variables-are-global/1563184#1563184).

Answer (score 0):

A better practice would be to store your object in the Application state.

`Application["MyObject"] = new SomeClass();`

Comment: Believe it or not, Microsoft says to use a static instead.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879023/what-is-the-life-span-of-a-field-in-a-static-class/4879119#4879119

Comment: Wow, that really surprised me! I suppose the Application object has been superseded by the Cache object anyway.